# Is the growth factor of STL vector in C++ constant or adaptive?

Tags: c++, vector

Does the standard specify whether `std::vector`'s growth vector has to be constant, or can it be adaptive?

On my linux and mac machines, I believe it's always constant (observed empirically -- but I have not checked if this is maintained at very large sizes). 2x latter, and I can't recall on the former.

Comment: With "adaptive", do you mean something like "if <4KB round to the next power of 2" ? Because that sort of thing is entirely allowed.

Comment: @MSalters By "adaptive," I guess I'm just referring to a situation where the growth factor *adapts* to the situation it's in, but I think that would require some kind of foreknowledge/predictive capability, about what is to come in terms of growing the vector, so that may not be applicable here since if we had that knowledge, then we probably would've just reserved the space in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The standard requires that vector has [amortized constant growth](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#14.sentence-2).  As long as that is maintained, the implementation can do whatever it wants.

All implementations I have seen use a constant growth factor, but doesn't mean it has to be that way, as long as the invariant is maintained.

Answer (score 2):

The standard specifies that the growth of a `std::vector` has to be O(1)+.

Doubling is a common strategy.

There is some academic research that suggests that growing by the *golden ratio* might be better. It would be nice if it was configurable, but nobody has convinced the C++ standards committee of the merit of doing that.

Comment: The original STL (from which the container, iterator, and function objects in the C++ standard library) doubled the size on overflow. Implementations these days typically grow by a factor of 1.5.